# what are the different approches to solve this problem?

Tags: probability

This problem is from one of the [blog from codeforces](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/62690). Can anyone tell me how to start this problem.

**Problem:** You teach informatics in a class with 20 students. When someone has a birthday, you must let the whole class to play games instead of learning algorithms and using Excel. Maybe some students have birthday on the same day, so there would be fewer than 20 wasted days during a year? Find EV of the number of days when at least one student has birthday.

Comment: Linearity of expectation is particularly powerful and should be one of the first things you try to think about using whenever faced with a question about expected value.  The expected value of the total number of days where at least one student has a birthday is the sum of the expected values for each day of the year respectively.  So, we have transformed the question from "What is the expected number of wasted days" to "What is the probability Jan1 is a wasted day" and multiplying that result by $365$ which should be much easier.

Comment: Note... trying to calculate the probability that there are exactly $k$ wasted days is a waste of time here.  While it may be an interesting exercise in its own right, and the theory behind how one could use that result for the purposes of expected value may be easier, it does not lead to an easily manipulatable expression and does not help the average beginning student actually find the expected value.  The whole purpose of a question phrased like this one is to emphasize the power of linearity of expectation, allowing us to calculate things with incredible ease where other methods may fail.